# QT 4 <->QT 5 Encoding

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to account for the use of both QT4 and QT5. The system uses both versions but they're in separate products that share common files.

I have found a solution that works but it has to do a version check each time and I would like to find a way to have a "one encoding fits both" scenario.

My current solution is something like this, using a micro sign (µ) as an example.

The QT 4 encoding only needs a nibble from the byte which in this case is (\xb5)

Qt 5 needs the whole byte (\xc2\xb5).

I have also tried using the C++ code (\u00B5) but that produced a Î 1/4

c++

```
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
print out a QString with the code \xc2\xb5
#else
print out a QString with the code \xb5
#endif
```

Is there a better way to do this and avoid the need for a version check? I have around 50 of these checks that I would like to eliminate.

Comment: `\xb5` is a byte and `\xc2\xb5` is 2 bytes. U+C2B5 is not a valid Unicode character: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c2b5/index.htm

Comment: Alright, but this solution works, I just want to find a better way of doing it

Comment: @RichardCritten that site is mistaken, it's a valid character (it's even displayed as such!). See [what unicode-table.com thinks of it](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=c2b5). But anyway, you were checking the wrong thing: `C2 B5` is a UTF-8 string, which corresponds to U+00B5 code point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default, `QString` in Qt4, when working with `char*` or `const char*` arguments, treats them as ASCII strings (see [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#QString-8)), while in Qt5 they are UTF-8 strings ([the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-7)). So what you think "only needs a nibble from the byte" is actually "needs the ASCII value for the character". The `µ` character has code 0xB5 in Latin1, which is the default code page for Qt4's ASCII. And the `C2 B5` is the UTF-8 representation of the code point corresponding to this character.

So what you actually need to do is to avoid the constructor `QString::QString(const char*)`, and instead use [`QString::fromUtf8`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8) explicitly.

Comment: I tried saying text=columnTitle (""QString::fromUtf8("\xb5")""s) in my .ini file (which generates the cpp, h) it returned an error that I'm miss a ) before QString. This error does NOT occur with using  text=columnTitle (""\xb5""s)

Comment: @Yeet because you're feeding an Latin1 string to the function which expects UTF-8.

Comment: how can I make that return in the UTF-8 then? Is it an issue with using the .ini to generate the files?

Comment: would using the encoding for mu rather than the microsecond be something to try?

Comment: @Yeet you say in the OP that `\xc2\xb5` works in Qt5 — why not use it now? It _is_ the UTF-8 representation of the _micro sign_.

Comment: QT4 shows 2 symbols rather than only the microsecond

Comment: @Yeet then you must have done it wrong. See [this simple example](https://pastebin.com/raw/TE1xj0d2) where it works both in Qt4 and in Qt5.

Comment: The problem appears to be where it is generated from an .ini, the encoding is picked up but the QString::fromUtf8 is ignored and is printed as if it were part of the string

Comment: I used a different encoding else where that worked for another symbol QChar(0x2715) but the problem of being printed as part of the string persists

Comment: That looks like a separate problem worth of its own question. But if you do ask, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem. Otherwise it'll be hard to guess what your actual problem is.